# How do I modify a library in python and use it?

Tags: python, github, scikit-learn

To be more specific, I want to modify some functions in `scikit-learn` and import it to python. But I do not know how to work.

I tried to modify .py files directly from where the sklearn stores in my local directory, but there are some files I could not open to modify, such as those with `.cp36-win_amd64`.

Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 22):

Delete the scikit-learn package, clone the version you are interested in from [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn). Go to the directory where you've cloned it and run:

```
pip3 install -e ./
```

This will install the package in development mode. Any changes you make will take effect the next time you run your application.

Comment: Hi Alex, just one last question. If I make any changes to files in the directory, how do I make sure it will take effect? Do I just import the library again or do I have to rerun pip statement?

Comment: No pip installation required. If you are making an application that runs as a daemon or service(think tornado), you may need to restart it.

Comment: Hi Alex, the thing is, after using pip3, it generates some new files with .cp36-win_amd64. And After I make some changes in files like .pyx, it will not take effect if I just import the library again.

Comment: Ah pyx, you should have started with this. Then you'll need to run `pip install -e. /` cause those need to be recompiled after changes.

Answer (score 9):

Modifying source files is not a good idea...especially if you want to use the "unmodified" version later on. My advice would to:

- Checkout the Scikit-learn repository on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn)
- Give it a custom name (e.g. myScikitLearn)
- Install it using pip install -e
- All modifications made to myScikitLearn source files can then be used immediately in your code

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Can you be more specific about how to Give it a custom name and make modifications? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just rename the scikit-learn root folder (the folder that contains the setup.py file) to something like myScikitLearn). Install it using "pip install -e myScikitLearn/". You can then modify the source file inside the myScikitLearn directory.